# Is it possible to know why installation of Windows 8 was unsuccessful?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Currently my system runs on Windows 7. Recently I tried to install(upgrade to 8 from 7) Windows 8 twice and failed. The installation worked fine for almost the end. The installation procedure restarted my system twice and worked up to the 'Getting Devices Ready' section.

After the 3rd restart a screen with an error message showed. I can't read that error because that screen didn't even appeared for a second. When the error appeared the system restarted for 3 more times, showing the error each time.

Then the installation procedure was stopped and it reverted back the changes made. When this was completed, the system started with Windows 7. Is there any way to know why the installation was unsuccessful ? I mean, is there any log or something else about the installation details in my system ?

Comment: There was an update just released related to upgrades, [2952664](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2952664), which is available from Windows update. The KB entry is vague about what it fixes or does but likely worth installing and trying the upgrade again.

Comment: @techie007 I had a look at the link you gave. Where is the location of those log files in my system ?

Comment: @Brian I can't find such an update for my Windows 7 in the Windows Update. Why ?

Comment: @Tom They're listed in the accepted answer (%WINDIR% is a variable that represents your Windows directory)