# Cannot find Windows Update 2952664 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Recently I asked a question-  [Is it possible to know why installation of Windows 8 was unsuccessful?](https://superuser.com/questions/745069/is-it-possible-to-know-why-installation-of-windows-8-was-unsuccessful)

In it they said about an update 2952664. But I can't find such an update in my Windows update. Why can't I find it there ?

Comment: It is possible that the update is hidden, due to its relevance, There's an option that enables you to see hidden updates within Windows Update. Also, you should wait a little before asking a follow up question (this relating to your previous question, as you only got a comment 11 hours after your question was posted).

Comment: Also possibility for "superseded" or un-needed on your setup, it is odd the lack of info provided at the location. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2952664 I left feedback there so they would clarify, please do the same.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Its not hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it is shown under "optional" fixes:

[image]

Here are the download links for the update if you still can't find it:

32Bit: http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2014/04/windows6.1-kb2952664-x86_0d194075316e8e2a5c70c2ffeda1def37eddd5e1.msu

64Bit: http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2014/04/windows6.1-kb2952664-x64_64fa470c9532bb78dfae728f0c0122dd65eff933.msu

Comment: I downloaded and tried to install it. Then it said 'The update is not applicable for your computer'. Why it is so ?

Comment: this update is for Win7 Sp1 (Build 7601). Maybe you still use the Win7 RTM (Build 7600)